# ActiveCell.Formula = Variable Not Working

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to fill the active cell with a formula. An example of the desired formula is =SUMIF(K30:K40,DescVar,E30:E40) where DescVar is string variable.

Here is the snip of code that is giving me problems:

```
If Selection.Value <> DescVar Then

Selection.Offset(1, -6).Select

Dim CalcRow As Integer, FromRow As Integer, ToRow As Integer
CalcRow = ActiveCell.Row
FromRow = CalcRow + 1
ToRow = FromRow + 10

Dim SumFormula As String
SumFormula = "='SUMIF(K" & FromRow & ":K" & ToRow & "," & DescVar & ",E" & FromRow & ":E" & ToRow & ")"

ActiveCell.Formula = SumFormula

End If
```

Any ideas?

Comment: what is the problem with your code?  What happens that shouldn't?  You probably need to remove the `'`

Comment: I keep receiving Run-Time error '1004'. Application -defined or object-defined error

Comment: On which line?  Did you try it after removing the `'` in the formula?

Comment: I did, I receive it on "ActiveCell.Formula = SumFormula".

Comment: Change to `Selection.Formula = SumFormula`  If that does not work.  Put `Debug.Print SumFormula` just before that line and make sure the formula looks correct.

Comment: I just tried both of those suggestions. I got the same result with the first suggestion and while the code ran when I put Debug.Print SumFormula in front of the line, it didn't end up putting the formula in the cell.

Comment: Since you need something like `=SUMIF(K1:K10,"foo",E1:E10)`, you have to add the quotes around `DescVar`. Regarding `Debug.Print`, check the output in the Immediate Window.

Comment: `Debug.Print` will put the string in the immediate window for you to review not in a cell.

Comment: BigBen, when I put quotations around DescVar it doesn't return the variables value. Instead the formula that pastes is =SUMIF(K1:K10,@DescVar,E1:E10)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the end result needs to be something like `=SUMIF(K1:K10,"foo",E1:E10)`, you need to add the quotes around `DescVar`, and they need to be doubled up:

```
SumFormula = "=SUMIF(K" & FromRow & ":K" & ToRow & ",""" & DescVar & """,E" & FromRow & ":E" & ToRow & ")"
```